# ggplot text is not rendering properly in Quarto if using specific fonts

Tags: r, ggplot2, quarto

I am rendering a quarto document to pdf using Calibri Light font (the one we use in my workplace) but ggplot figures are not rendering properly if I try to render the document to pdf (it does render well when redering it to html). The document options look like this

```
---
title: "Some title here"
author: "Marc Bosch"
execute:
  warning: false
  error: false
  message: false
  echo: false
format:
  html: 
    code-fold: true
    code-summary: "Show the code"
    fig-width: 8
    embed-resources: true
    css: styles.css
  pdf:
    mainfont: Calibri Light
---
```

Now, if I try to use Calibri Light for the documents, when rendered it looks

[image: like this]

With any other font (I've used Helvetica), it looks

[image: the correct way]

To change the font, I use a custom theme with a `plot_font` parameter, the relevant part of the function looks like this.

```
theme(
plot.title = element_text(size = title_size, face = "bold", family = plot_font), 
plot.subtitle = element_text(size = subtitle_size, family = plot_font),
axis.title.y = element_text(size = x_size), 
axis.title.x = element_text(size = y_size),
axis.text.x = element_text(size = axis_x_size, vjust = x_vjust),
axis.text.y = element_text(size = axis_y_size), 
plot.caption = element_text(size = 8.5, hjust = 0, 
                            colour = rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.65), 
                            family = plot_font), 
strip.text = element_text(size = 13),
legend.position = legend_position, 
legend.text = element_text(size = 13),
title = element_text(family = plot_font), 
text = element_text(family = plot_font),
panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
)
```

I have tried several pdf engines, with no good result. I have the following code to make sure it registers the fonts correctly.

```
library(extrafont)
loadfonts(quiet = TRUE)
```

I can't post the data because it contains personal information, but the code I'm using for the plots essentially looks like this.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable_x) +
       geom_bar(fill = my_colour) +
       labs(title = "something") +
       function_corporate_theme(plot_font = "Calibri Light")
```

I should expect it to render properly.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example, not just a relevant part :) ??

Comment: Not really (personal data), but posted an example of what I'm doing.

Comment: I am not saying to give your personal data...just asking for the whole ggplot code and you could use built in dataset like `mtcars` to showcase your problem

Comment: You could use some made-up data that show the problem. Then share all the code, including the made-up data. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .